# R: coefficients from glmnet's ridge regression do not match

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

In ridge regression, the coefficients have the analytical form:

[image]
where lambda is a positive number.

Using `glmnet`, I performed a ridge regression with `alpha =0`, `lambda = 1`. However, why don't `fit1$beta` match with those of the analytical formula?

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(3)
x = matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20)
y = rnorm(100)
lambda <- 1
fit1 = glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda)
> head(fit1$beta)
6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
             s0
V1 -0.016685052
V2  0.024373749
V3 -0.008228917
V4  0.035215872
V5 -0.008518129
V6 -0.001925812
> head(solve(t(x) %*% x + lambda * diag(p)) %*% t(x) %*% y)
            [,1]
[1,] -0.05338655
[2,]  0.04285142
[3,] -0.03454318
[4,]  0.08704770
[5,] -0.02599216
[6,] -0.02031802
```

Comment: Similar question on CV: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-is-glmnet-ridge-regression-giving-me-a-different-answer-than-manual-calculat